# .net display localised currency format without currency symbol

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, view, string-formatting, currency

I have a localised site that needs to display a currency field.

The currency will remain the same and does not change per culture

I have tried to format the currency like this:

```
@String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C}", item.GrossPayment)
```

but this does not work, because it displays the currency symbol native to that culture.

I want to display €12 but the above displays ¥12

So, the format is what I want, but without the currency symbol which I can just hardcode

so next I tried this:

```
€@String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:N}", item.GrossPayment)
```

In ja-JP

> €12.00

gets displayed so this gets over my currency symbol problem, but now the format is wrong as in the ja-JP culture there should be no decimal point or trailing zeroes it should display as

> €12

Any ideas how I can preserve the format while specifying my own currency symbol  in a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the currency symbol in the culture. Create a copy of the culture and then change whatever you want:

```
var culture = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "€";
@String.Format(culture, "{0:C}", 12);
```

Maybe you could preserve the copy of the culture in some static variable, so won't have to clone on every request...

Comment: Yep, that works, thanks. Seems like an almighty hack though. Cant believe there isn't some built in mechanism to achieve what would seem to me to be a fairly ordinary requirement